# Spatial join in Python invalid parameters

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7, spatial-join

I'm getting an error when excecuting a script thats suppose to spatial join two point layers. Code says:

> Error 000561 Invalid parameters

But, I'm pretty certain that they are correct.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong with the code?

I've read that it might be because multiple points might be withing distance of parameters of one point so that it requires fieldmapping. But I have not figured out how I'm suppose to do this.

```
import arcpy, sys, string, os, datetime, copy

# Local Path
sti_endring = 
r"Y:\N50_Kartdata\Arbeidsfiler\Kontroll\Script\N250_Kontroll\Dataopp
datering\Endringsdata\finn_endring.gdb\\"

# Local variables:
N250_HoydetallObjkoord = sti_endring + "N250_HoydetallObjkoord"
N50_HoydetallObjkoord = sti_endring + "N50_HoydetallObjkoord"
HoydetallObjkoord_joined = sti_endring + "HoydetallObjkoord_joined"

# Process: Spatial Join
target_features = N250_HoydetallObjkoord
join_features = N50_HoydetallObjkoord
out_feature_class = HoydetallObjkoord_joined
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, 
out_feature_class, "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "KEEP_ALL", "INTERSECT", "350 
Meters", "")
```

Comment: What are your N250_HoydetallObjkoord, N50_HoydetallObjkoord and  HoydetallObjkoord_joined variables set to?

Comment: They are set equal to original name, so no change in variable.

Comment: What original name?  In any event where you set them should be part of the code snippet that you present.

Comment: You need an r in front of "Y:\ to deal with those single backslashes as a raw string.

Comment: The "r" didn't transfer over when i copied the code, I've added it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid mentionning the distance_field_name parameter, as it is not applicable with the match_option parameter.

Also, and more importantly, it seems you are skipping the field_mapping parameter (reference syntax is available [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm)). 
Either add it, stating it is null ('#') or specify what the subsequent parameters are. These two options look like this:

Either

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, 
out_feature_class, "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "KEEP_ALL", "#", "INTERSECT", "350 
Meters")
```

Or:

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, 
out_feature_class, "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "KEEP_ALL", match_option="INTERSECT", search_radius="350 Meters")
```

Comment: Thanks, that got the code working. I didn't think i needed to add field_mapping paramater if i did not intend to use it.